# CREATE DATABASE query fails

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli

OK, so i was testing my install script and I got an error that the database does not exist, which means that the database create query failed,

here is my full code:

```
<?php
if(!file_exists('install.lock')) {
if(!isset($_GET['success'])) {
echo "
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
    <title> Lorem Ipsum Dolor </title>
    <link href='../assets/css/style.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <style type='text/css'>
      body {
        text-align:center;
      }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id='containerAdmin'>
<br />
<h2> Lorem Ipsum </h2> <br />
<h4> Please follow the steps below to install your new copy of ticketExpress </h4> <br />
<form action='' method='post'>
<input type='text' name='dbhost' placeholder='MySQL Database Host' size='23'>
<input type='text' name='dbuser' placeholder='MySQL Database Username' size='23'>
<input type='text' name='dbpass' placeholder='MySQL Database Password' size='23'>
 <br />
<input type='text' name='admin_username' placeholder='Admin Username'> 
<input type='text' name='admin_password' placeholder='Admin Password'> <br />
<input type='text' name='sitename' placeholder='Website Name' size='23'> <br />
<input type='submit' name='install' class='btn btn-primary' value='Install'>
</form>
<p> Lorem Ipsum Dolor </p> <br />
</body>
</html>
"; 

if(isset($_POST['install'])) {
$AdminUsername = HtmlSpecialChars(strip_tags($_POST['admin_username']));
$AdminPassword = HtmlSpecialChars(strip_tags($_POST['admin_password']));
$dbhost = strip_tags($_POST['dbhost']);
$dbuser = strip_tags($_POST['dbuser']);
$dbpass = strip_tags($_POST['dbpass']);
$sitename = strip_tags($_POST['sitename']);
if(!$con) {
echo "Please configure database information in config.php";
}
$sql = "CREATE TABLE tickets
(
ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
Name VARCHAR(32),
Email VARCHAR(40),
Subject VARCHAR(40),
Message TEXT(500),
open VARCHAR(10),
TimeCreated VARCHAR(40),
TimeUpdated VARCHAR(40),
hash VARCHAR(100)
)";
$sql2 = "CREATE TABLE config 
(
AdminUsername VARCHAR(32),
AdminPassword VARCHAR(32)
)";
$sql3 = "INSERT INTO config (AdminUsername,AdminPassword) VALUES ('$AdminUsername','$AdminPassword')";
if(empty($AdminUsername)) {
echo "Admin Username should not be empty!";
} elseif (empty($AdminPassword)) {
echo "Admin Password should not be empty!";
} elseif(empty($dbhost)) {
echo "MySQL Database Host should not be empty!";
} elseif(empty($dbuser)) {
echo "MySQL Database User should not be empty!";
/* } elseif(empty($dbname)) {
echo "MySQL Database Name should not be empty!"; */
} elseif(empty($sitename)) {
echo "Please enter a name for your new installation (It can be whatever you want)";
}
else {
$file = fopen('../configuration/config.php','r+');
fwrite($file, '<?php $dbhost = "'. $dbhost.'"; $dbuser = "'. $dbuser.'"; $dbpass = "'. $dbpass.'"; $dbname = "lol"; $sitename = "'. $sitename.'"; $con = new mysqli ($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);');
include('../configuration/config.php');
$con->query("CREATE DATABASE lol");
$con->query($sql);
$con->query($sql2);
$con->query("DELETE FROM config");
$con->query($sql3);
fopen('install.lock','w');
header('Location: ../index.php');
}
}
}
} else {
echo "installation is locked";
}
```

The following line is failing me:

```
$con->query("CREATE DATABASE lol");
```

does anyone know why it won't work?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: on a different page, where It has to establish a new database connection I get the database not found error: Warning: mysqli::mysqli() [<a href='mysqli.mysqli'>mysqli.mysqli</a>]: (42000/1049): Unknown database 'lol' in C:\wamp\www\ticketExpress\configuration\config.php on line 1

Comment: Try print after include your properties, and check the error.log for the message

Comment: also, im using WAMP so there is not eror.log file :/

Comment: What? You connect the database name lol, and then you try create database name lol? Its paradox :D

Comment: Try doing `echo $con->error` right after your create database query.

Comment: When you are connecting with mysqli you shouldn't set database.

Comment: CREATE DATABASE lol failed.. clearly MySQL didn't find that funny..

Comment: @haydensmith does the user being used, have database creation rights?

Comment: The problem is the connection object is being created with a database that doesn't exist yet. See my answer.

Comment: Instead of just blindly calling `$con->query()` and assuming you're infallible, maybe you should check the return status of those calls to see if they were successful or not, and return an appropriate error if they were not.

Comment: Fixed it, looks like J. Robertson was right

Answer (score 2):

So if I understand your code correctly, you're writing code to a config file, then including that config file to access your connection object. Here's the problem - your connection object is being constructed under the assumption that the database lol has already been created. That's not true.

What you need to do is declare the mysqli object WITHOUT a database defined, like so:

```
fwrite($file, '<?php $dbhost = "'. $dbhost.'"; $dbuser = "'. $dbuser.'"; $dbpass = "'. $dbpass.'"; $sitename = "'. $sitename.'"; $con = new mysqli ($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);');
```

Comment: then what should I do?

Comment: My answer included the proper code to fix your problem, but I'm glad you solved it. Could you please mark this as the answer? There's a green checkmark below the up down arrows to mark it as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I feel J.Robertsons answer should work. You are trying to connect to DB lol before creating it. If for some reason its still not working after making that change, add the following to your connect statement so you can see the error.

```
or die("Could not connect: " . mysqli_error());
```

Your code should look like this:

```
fwrite($file, '<?php $dbhost = "'. $dbhost.'"; $dbuser = "'. $dbuser.'"; $dbpass = "'. $dbpass.'"; $dbname = "lol"; $sitename = "'. $sitename.'"; $con = new mysqli ($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass)  or die("Could not connect: " . mysqli_error());');
```